Combinatorial Benders Papers which solve MIPs with binary master problems and continuous subproblems having subproblem objective functions
I am currently solving a problem of the aforementioned type containing Big-M constraints.
The seminal paper by Codato, G., & Fischetti, M., dated 2006, Combinatorial Benders' cuts for mixed-integer linear programming, Operations Research, 54(4), 756-766 does not explicitly cater to this problem type, as it was only mentioned in passing.
Also, I have not been successful in locating such papers be it those which require a reformulation to fit the standard formulation mentioned in the paper or others which explicitly retained the subproblem objective.
Are there papers that address this?

The following paper can be helpful.

Laporte, G., & Louveaux, F. V. (1993). The integer L-shaped method for
stochastic integer programs with complete recourse. Operations
Research Letters, 13(3), 133–142.
https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6377(93)90002-X

Though it is for stochastic programming, it applies to deterministic problem (scenario number = 1).

If your subproblem is pure Linear Programming, the standard Benders decomposition (Benders 1962) applies.

Unfortunately, this is not the case, as Big -M constraints renders slow convergence

The cut in that paper is more like a no- good cut which is not enough to ensure fast convergence.
